# UserProfile has no user when trying to clean data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to clean data by lowercasing all my users nicknames. Here is code:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def clean(self):
        self.user.username = self.user.username.lower()
```

However I get `UserProfile has no user.

I am noob at Django, but do I understand corectly, that whenever we are saving our models - clean(), which I have written, is used? Is that correct? So where is my mistake?

EDIT:

```
def register(request):
    # Like before, get the request's context.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()


            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render_to_response(
            'registration.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

Comment: Please show *exactly* what you are doing when you get that error.

Comment: I am trying to register a new user. I added register()

Comment: an error traceback would be really helpful and please post your form code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model clean methods are not called by the save process, but by the form when you call is_valid() there. You could have seen that for yourself by looking at the traceback - it is always useful information.

At the point is_valid is called, of course, the profile does not have a user, hence the error.

I must say though that very little of this makes any sense anyway. Why have you put that code in the Profile model, rather than the User one? Even better, it should be in the User *form*, in a `clean_username` method, where it should *return* the lower-cased value.